# On gradient descent on $\beta \mapsto \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^{m} r_i^2(\beta)$

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent, neural-networks, mean-square-error

In the gradient descent algorithm that is used in minimizing a cost function. We give the general gradient descent update rule:

$$ x_{n+1} = x_n - \lambda \nabla f(x_n) $$

We want to apply it to the MSE function given by:

$$ C(\beta) = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^{m} r_i^2(\beta)$$

where we have $m$ functions $\mathbf {r} = (r_{1},\dots ,r_{m})$ of $n$ variables $\boldsymbol{\beta}=(\beta_{1},\ldots \beta_{n}),$ with $m\geq n,$
In the documentation of some training algorithms, the gradient descent algorithm applied to this MSE function is given by:
$$\Delta\beta = - \lambda \nabla C(x_n)$$ where $\Delta\beta$ is just the update or incrementation of $\beta$, or it is given by:

$$\Delta\beta = -\lambda J^{T}_r r$$

where $J$ is the Jacobian matrix.

In the second vector formula, shouldn't it be $\Delta\beta = -\frac{2}{m}\lambda J^{T}_r r$?

Comment: The step-size parameter $\lambda$ does not have to be the same in the two formulations.

Comment: So they defined the new $\lambda$ as $\frac{2}{m}\lambda$?

Comment: Alternatively, one can just rescale the cost function by that constant since the minimizers will be the same